# Live search (or autocomplete) through database from Swing

Tags: java, swing, search, jdbc, autocomplete

I am trying to do "google" search. User types something - programm going to DB and returns with the list of suggestions. I'm using AutoComplete package, but unsure if in the right way, because i'am not getting the list of suggestions below combo, so i can see and scroll through him, but it automatically chooses one suggestion from the list and puts him to the field. Also if for example at first user start search with letter "I.." the autocomplete do the job (as i described above) and then  if user wants to type the name of some other article like "A.." the combo just refreshes itself with previos result, so search really becomes not available.

```
class SuggestArticleNameActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    Vector<String> suggestions = new Vector<>();
                    try {
                        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD)) {
                            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM Article WHERE Article.name LIKE ?");
                            String typed = comboBoxSearchArticle.getEditor().getItem().toString();
                                pstmt.setString(1, "%"+typed+"%");
                                ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery();
                                while (result.next()) suggestions.add(result.getString("name"));
                                            Collections.sort(suggestions);
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    comboBoxSearchArticle.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(suggestions.toArray(new String[suggestions.size()])));
                    return null;
                }
```

Besides AutoComplete there is other questions: am i using the proper Listener and is this code thread-safe ? If there is more efficient ways, please let me know them.

Comment: Have you tried implementing autocomplete with a fake suggestion list (without interaction with a database)?

Comment: @Dmytro yes, it works as fine. I edited my post with more description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to implement **ItemListener**:

```
class SuggestArticleNameActionListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
       if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          Object item = event.getItem();
          // implement your logic here
       }
    }       
}
```

Comment: could you explain why ? From my vision the logic is the same

Comment: There are a lot of events that ActionListener listens to. For example, it listens to previous value deselect event. That is why it refreshes with previous result.

Comment: So then it's better to implement ItemListener for performance purposes ?
I implemented listener, but the problem is still having place.

Comment: I am not sure. You said that it works fine using fake data. So maybe the problem is in your sql query?

Comment: i'am using sql which you see above. for now i'm thinking that the autocomplete api is the problem. because it's not allows empty combo and also instead of showing the suggestions below the combo's field it chooses one of them and completes user's input. If thats the way it works, then how to modify AutoComplete API so it will response my purposes ?